# How to raise the amount of product price digits?

Tags: magento2, price, product-prices

I'm using Magento2. When I add a new product with a price of 416000000 the price is reset to 100000000 after save. How can I fix it?

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21508397/magento-maximum-price-more-than-100-million

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the restriction on database level where the product price is stored in a colum of type `decimal(12,4)`.
This means there can be 8 digits to the left of the decimal point (12-4) and 4 to the right of the decimal point.

If you want to change this, wou will have to modify all tables and columns where the price is stored and set the type of the colums to at least `decimal(13,4)` according to your example.

Check out these tables where the product price, quote and quote item totals, order and order item totals price are stored and identify colums which you need to update (no guarantee for completeness):

**catalog price table**

- table `catalog_product_entity_decimal`, column `value`

**quote and sales tables**

- table `sales_order`, quite a lot of columns. Most important are the `base_*` and `total_*` colums,  `grand_total`, `subtotal`.
- table `sales_order_item`
- table `sales_order_payment`
- table `sales_invoice` and `sales_invoice_item`
- table `sales_creditmemo` and `sales_creditmemo_item`
- table `quote`, similar/the same colums as in the `sales_order` table
- table `quote_item`

**index tables**

- table `catalog_product_index_price`, column `price`
- table `catalog_product_index_price_tmp`, column `price`
- table `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`, column `price`

also check out the other index tables for bundle, configurable and downloadable products (if needed).

I hope this helps you getting started with it. I'd say that's a lot of work to update all the colums in your database.

Also you have to do some intensive testing to see and check if the price gets somewhere reset again after updating all your columns.